# Jenkins build without maven

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, devops

I have a java project which I build and export it as a jar using eclipse. Then I deploy the jar.
Also my project uses dependencies e.g. Apache POI etc. I include these jars in the build path and then clean build and export it as a jar.
I want to build the jar using Jenkins. Please suggest the script and command to perform the same task without using maven. I have to build the code from Gitlab.

Comment: Hi @Abhimanyu, I am confusing, do you want to use jenkins or gitlab to build the jars? If you have a docker where you can run the same commands that launch eclipse (such as a gradle script), you can launch the process inside that container. Does this help?

Comment: #1 Why not maven? Hardware limits? #2 My hobbies is to mavenize old or legacy projects. May I help you? #3 Do you  have all the required jars to compile your app? #4 Do you need just compile all in one jar or apart of that, deploy ? #5 ant is an option for you?

Comment: @AlejandroVisiedoGarcía I don't have docker. so got to build using groovy

Comment: @JRichardsz 
1 - Workplace restrictions - legacy project.
2 - Thanks for help but can't mavenize it
3 - yes i do have all required jars
4 - compile into one jar and then deploy as well
5 - No, can we do the same in groovy

Comment: @Abhimanyu sorry my insistence. I mavenized impossible applications. #1 As I said you, I can help you with nothing in return :D.  #2 With ant, (father of maven), you can automate compile steps to one simple command. Why groovy? #3 Where will be deployed your jar? java -jar ....

Comment: @JRichardsz 1. Thank you. 2. - Project manager insists on groovy. let try to convince him with ant. 3.- Deployed on WAS